# IE & Edge border dashed and border radius issue

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in IE and Edge when I use `border-style: dashed;` and `border-radius: .375rem;` on the same element:

```
div {
  padding: 5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  border-radius: .375rem;
}
```

The following is what I get (those weird things in the corners).

[image]

For the reason unknown to me I cannot reproduce this in jsfiddle or anywhere outside my document. Would be greatful for any advice on what this can be at all cause I am out of ideas (I am talking about those weird things in the corners).

Comment: Did you end up figuring out anything about this behavior. I've only come close to recreating it by adjusting the browser zoom level.

Comment: @llamaoo7, no it's still present.